# Unable to remove a managed account?

Tags: service

All suggestions and answers are really appreciated.

I have Sharepoint installed on a Test computer and I did something very stupid. I deleted a service account domain\spupsync ( was using it for user profile Sync service ) from AD before deleting it from Managed Accounts in Sharepoint. Now I am unable to remove this account from Managed Accounts I get the following error

> " Error  The account domain\SPupsync is still being used by these
>   components:  User Profile Synchronization Service.  Troubleshoot
>   issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.  Correlation ID:
>   1a2bc365-70a8-4edd-9644-e5f468a93bef "

and it made things worse I am unable to access the Configure Service accounts page , I get this error

> " Error  Some or all identity references could not be translated. 
>   Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.  Correlation
>   ID: 5a818ddd-a8a3-46a5-9a6c-d5f09b30f9b7 "

I have tried removing the account from PS using the `remove-spmanagedaccount` , no luck 
`Remove-SPManagedAccount` : The account domain\SPupsync is still being used by these
components:

> User Profile Synchronization Service.

Comment: have you ever been able to fix this usse? thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following steps:

1. Create a new service account.
2. Set the user profile service to use this newly created service account.
3. Then try to delete the original account.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply Nadeem, I created a new service account and set it for user profile service but it didnt help , I still get the same errors. Also I used remove-spserviceapplicationpool and removed the User profile app Pool as well but no luck...

Comment: I tried creating the same account (domain\spupsync) in AD and that account now shows up in managed accounts but I am still unable to delete it. I found this link it may be usefull if someone else has the same problem http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=312

Comment: try assigned new service account via powershell and force option (if exist)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a test environment. If you don't need the content in the user profiles & config data try deleting the entire UPS and see if you can delete the managed account.

Alternatively if you do need the profile data:

- backup the SQL UPS databases
- Delete the UPS
- Restore the UPS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985419.aspx